# QGIS Transformations

Tags: qgis

Where does QGIS get it's default transformations? The reason I am asking is that the default transformation between NAD83 (3735 in this case) and WGS84 in QGIS differs from Esri products. This is really causing me a headache as I constantly move data back and forth between these two projections and also move between these two software platforms. I want to determine to root cause instead of simply adding a custom transformation to QGIS as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how the the default is selected, but all candidate operations that Proj library supports can be found with projinfo utility. Probably the default transformation must be valid for the whole area covered by the data and perhaps the one that has the best accuracy value stored into the EPSG database is selected, but this is just my guess.

In your case there are 6 candidates but I include only two. You can run the command yourself for reading the rest.

```
projinfo -s epsg:3735 -t epsg:4326 --spatial-test intersects

Candidate operations found: 6
-------------------------------------
Operation No. 1:

unknown id, Inverse of SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet) + NAD83 to WGS 84 (49), 1 m, USA - Ohio

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=us-ft +xy_out=m +step +inv +proj=lcc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=-82.5 +lat_1=40.0333333333333 +lat_2=38.7333333333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=ohhpgn.gsb +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Inverse of SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet) + NAD83 to WGS 84 (49)",
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["NAD83 / Ohio South (ftUS)",
            BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
                DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4269]],
            CONVERSION["SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet)",
                METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
                    ID["EPSG",9802]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",38,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8821]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-82.5,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8822]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",40.0333333333333,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8823]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",38.7333333333333,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8824]],
                PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",1968500,
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                    ID["EPSG",8826]],
                PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                    ID["EPSG",8827]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["easting (X)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
                AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
            ID["EPSG",3735]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Inverse of SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet)",
            METHOD["Inverse of Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
                ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",9802]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",38,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8821]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-82.5,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8822]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",40.0333333333333,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8823]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",38.7333333333333,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8824]],
            PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",1968500,
                LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                ID["EPSG",8826]],
            PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                ID["EPSG",8827]],
            ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",13434]]],
    STEP[
        COORDINATEOPERATION["NAD83 to WGS 84 (49)",
            SOURCECRS[
                GEOGCRS["NAD83",
                    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4269]]],
            TARGETCRS[
                GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4326]]],
            METHOD["NTv2",
                ID["EPSG",9615]],
            PARAMETERFILE["Latitude and longitude difference file","ohhpgn.gsb"],
            OPERATIONACCURACY[1.0],
            ID["DERIVED_FROM(EPSG)",1745]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["USA - Ohio"],
        BBOX[38.4,-84.83,42.33,-80.51]]]

-------------------------------------
Operation No. 2:

unknown id, Inverse of SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet) + NAD83 to WGS 84 (1), 4 m, North America - Canada and USA (CONUS, Alaska mainland)

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=us-ft +xy_out=m +step +inv +proj=lcc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=-82.5 +lat_1=40.0333333333333 +lat_2=38.7333333333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=rad +xy_out=deg +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1

WKT2:2019 string:
CONCATENATEDOPERATION["Inverse of SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet) + NAD83 to WGS 84 (1)",
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["NAD83 / Ohio South (ftUS)",
            BASEGEOGCRS["NAD83",
                DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                ID["EPSG",4269]],
            CONVERSION["SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet)",
                METHOD["Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
                    ID["EPSG",9802]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",38,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8821]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-82.5,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8822]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",40.0333333333333,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8823]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",38.7333333333333,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8824]],
                PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",1968500,
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                    ID["EPSG",8826]],
                PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                    ID["EPSG",8827]]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["easting (X)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
                AXIS["northing (Y)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219]],
            ID["EPSG",3735]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    STEP[
        CONVERSION["Inverse of SPCS83 Ohio South zone (US Survey feet)",
            METHOD["Inverse of Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)",
                ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",9802]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of false origin",38,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8821]],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of false origin",-82.5,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8822]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",40.0333333333333,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8823]],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of 2nd standard parallel",38.7333333333333,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                ID["EPSG",8824]],
            PARAMETER["Easting at false origin",1968500,
                LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                ID["EPSG",8826]],
            PARAMETER["Northing at false origin",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["US survey foot",0.304800609601219],
                ID["EPSG",8827]],
            ID["INVERSE(EPSG)",13434]]],
    STEP[
        COORDINATEOPERATION["NAD83 to WGS 84 (1)",
            VERSION["DMA-N Am"],
            SOURCECRS[
                GEOGCRS["NAD83",
                    DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
                        ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4269]]],
            TARGETCRS[
                GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
                    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
                    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
                            ORDER[1],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
                            ORDER[2],
                            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                    ID["EPSG",4326]]],
            METHOD["Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)",
                ID["EPSG",9603]],
            PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8605]],
            PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8606]],
            PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                ID["EPSG",8607]],
            OPERATIONACCURACY[4.0],
            ID["EPSG",1188],
            REMARK["Derived at 354 stations."]]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["unknown"],
        AREA["North America - Canada and USA (CONUS, Alaska mainland)"],
        BBOX[23.81,-172.54,86.46,-47.74]]]

-------------------------------------
```

Comment: ok, which this tool in in the bin folder of the qgis install - I just cant seem to find a transformation that matches the one Esri uses ITRF00 Coord Frame -dx=0.995600...so this is an upstream proj question then?

Comment: The tool is a command line program.

Comment: right I got that part and got it working...would just be nice for these things to just "work" but alas...it's def an upstream PROJ question so I'll move this discussion over to their github repo issues...thanks